# Multiple UITextFields on one page to display date but only one of the UITextFields displays date slected from both DatePickers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, datepicker, uitextfield

I currently have 2 UITextFields, one needs to return a date and the other needs to return a time.

The issue(s) I'm having is that if I click on the first text field (i.e. "Date of birth:"), the date I select is returned (obviously this is exactly what I want to happen) however, if I click on the second text field (i.e. "Time of first meal:"), the second text field isn't updated but the first text field is (this is my first problem).

The next issue I'm having is that when I click on my second text field (i.e. "Time of first meal:"), the date is shown on the selector, not the time (I want the time to show).

I assume the two issues are related but I can't figure out what it is that I'm missing to distinguish the two pickers from one another.

The plan is to then have the third text field (i.e. "Time of last meal") also display a time (different to the second text field display) so I guess once I can get these two issues I'm currently having sorted, I can apply the same solution to the third text field.

As you can imagine (based on the amount of text fields I've got) I've cut down the code to only the bits that relate to the date pickers.

[Picture of text fields from my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTobK.png)

[Picture of date picker (the same picker shows up for both text fields)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEjgr.png)

```
import UIKit

class ProfileCreator: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

var output: Int = 0
var output2: Int = 0

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// DOB Selector From Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var DOBSelectorTextField: UITextField!

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(DOBtextField: UITextField) {
    let DOBPicker = UIDatePicker()
    DOBtextField.inputView = DOBPicker
    DOBPicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    DOBPicker.addTarget(self, action: "DOBpickerchanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(DOBtextField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    DOBtextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}

func DOBpickerchanged(DOBsender: UIDatePicker) {
    let DOBformatter = NSDateFormatter()
    DOBformatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
    DOBSelectorTextField.text = DOBformatter.stringFromDate(DOBsender.date)

}

// DOB Selector From Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //    

// First Meal Time Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var FirstMealTimeTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func FirstMealTimeTextField(FirstMealTimeSender: UITextField) {

    let FirstMealTimePicker = UIDatePicker()
    FirstMealTimeSender.inputView = FirstMealTimePicker
    FirstMealTimePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    FirstMealTimePicker.addTarget(self, action: "FirstMealTimeChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

}

func FirstMealTimeChanged(FirstMealTimesender: UIDatePicker) {
    let FirstMealtimeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    FirstMealtimeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    FirstMealTimeTextField.text = FirstMealtimeFormatter.stringFromDate(FirstMealTimesender.date)
}

// First Meal Time Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// DOB Selector From Text Field Start 2 //

    DOBSelectorTextField.delegate = self

// DOB Selector From Text Field End 2 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// First Meal Time Text Field Start 2 //

    FirstMealTimeTextField.delegate = self

// First Meal Time Text Field End 2 //

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Here is my entire code that relates to my "Create Profile" page. Maybe it will help with the understanding of what I've done so far. I'm fairly confident with creating pickers where the data comes from an array, the thing I'm struggling with is doing multiple date pickers on the same page.

```
import UIKit

class ProfileCreator: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

var output: Int = 0
var output2: Int = 0

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// DOB Selector From Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var DOBSelectorTextField: UITextField!

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(DOBtextField: UITextField) {
    let DOBPicker = UIDatePicker()
    DOBtextField.inputView = DOBPicker
    DOBPicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    DOBPicker.addTarget(self, action: "DOBpickerchanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(DOBtextField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    DOBtextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}

func DOBpickerchanged(DOBsender: UIDatePicker) {
    let DOBformatter = NSDateFormatter()
    DOBformatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"
    DOBSelectorTextField.text = DOBformatter.stringFromDate(DOBsender.date)

}

// DOB Selector From Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Gender Selector From Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var GenderSelectorTextField: UITextField!
var GenderSelectorData = ["Male", "Female"]
var GenderSelectorPicker = UIPickerView()

// Gender Selector From Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Height Whole Number Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var HeightWholeNumberTextField: UITextField!

// Height Whole Number Text Field Start 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Height Whole Number Unit Selector Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorTextField: UITextField!
var HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorData = ["m", "ft"]
var HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker = UIPickerView()

// Height Whole Number Unit Selector Text Field Start 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Height Decimal Number Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var HeightDecimalTextField: UITextField!

// Height Decimal Number Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Height Decimal Number Unit Selector Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorTextField: UITextField!
var HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorData = ["cm", "inch"]
var HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker = UIPickerView()

// Height Decimal Number Unit Selector Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Current Weight Whole Number Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var CurrentWeightWholeNumberTextField: UITextField!

// Current Weight Whole Number Text Field Start 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Current Weight Whole Number Unit Selector Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorTextField: UITextField!
var CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorData = ["kg", "lb"]
var CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker = UIPickerView()

// Current Weight Whole Number Unit Selector Text Field Start 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Current Weight Decimal Number Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var CurrentWeightDecimalNumberTextField: UITextField!

// Current Weight Decimal Number Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Current Weight Decimal Number Unit Selector Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorTextField: UITextField!
var CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorData = ["g", "oz"]
var CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker = UIPickerView()

// Current Weight Decimal Number Unit Selector Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Current Fitness Goal Selector Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorTextField: UITextField!
var CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorData = ["Lose Fat", "Gain Muscle", "Maintain Physique"]
var CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorPicker = UIPickerView()

// Current Fitness Goal Selector Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Weekly Activity Level Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var WeeklyActivityLevelTextField: UITextField!
var WeeklyActivityLevelTextFieldData = ["I am sedentary (little or no exercise)", "I am lightly active (light exercise/sports 1-3 days per week)", "I am moderately active (moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days per week)", "I am very active (hard exercise/sports 6-7 days a week)", "I am extra active (very hard exercise/sports & physical job or 2 x training"]
var WeeklyActivityLevelSelectorPicker = UIPickerView()

// Weekly Activity Level Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// First Meal Time Text Field Start 1 //

@IBOutlet weak var FirstMealTimeTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func FirstMealTimeTextField(FirstMealTimeSender: UITextField) {

    let FirstMealTimePicker = UIDatePicker()
    FirstMealTimeSender.inputView = FirstMealTimePicker
    FirstMealTimePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    FirstMealTimePicker.addTarget(self, action: "FirstMealTimeChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

}

func FirstMealTimeChanged(FirstMealTimesender: UIDatePicker) {
    let FirstMealtimeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    FirstMealtimeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    FirstMealTimeTextField.text = FirstMealtimeFormatter.stringFromDate(FirstMealTimesender.date)
}

// First Meal Time Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Last Meal Time Text Field Start 1 //



// Last Meal Time Text Field End 1 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Close keyboard start //

func closekeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    closekeyboard()
}

// Close keyboard end //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// DOB Selector From Text Field Start 2 //

    DOBSelectorTextField.delegate = self

// DOB Selector From Text Field End 2 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Gender Selector From Text Field Start 2 //

    GenderSelectorPicker.delegate = self
    GenderSelectorPicker.dataSource = self
    GenderSelectorTextField.inputView = GenderSelectorPicker

// Gender Selector From Text Field End 2 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Height Whole Number Unit Selector Text Field Start 2 //

    HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker.delegate = self
    HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker.dataSource = self
    HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorTextField.inputView = HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker

// Height Whole Number Unit Selector Text Field End 2 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Height Decimal Unit Selector Text Field Start 2 //

    HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker.delegate = self
    HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker.dataSource = self
    HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorTextField.inputView = HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker

// Height Decimal Unit Selector Text Field End 2 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Current Weight Whole Number Unit Selector Text Field Start 2 //

    CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker.delegate = self
    CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker.dataSource = self
    CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorTextField.inputView = CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker

// Current Weight Whole Number Unit Selector Text Field End 2 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Current Weight Decimal Unit Selector Text Field Start 2 //

    CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker.delegate = self
    CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker.dataSource = self
    CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorTextField.inputView = CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker

// Current Weight Decimal Unit Selector Text Field End 2 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Current Fitness Goal Selector Text Field Start 2 //

    CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorPicker.delegate = self
    CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorPicker.dataSource = self
    CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorTextField.inputView = CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorPicker

// Current Fitness Goal Selector Text Field End 2 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Weekly Activity Level Selector Text Field Start 2 //

    WeeklyActivityLevelSelectorPicker.delegate = self
    WeeklyActivityLevelSelectorPicker.dataSource = self
    WeeklyActivityLevelTextField.inputView = WeeklyActivityLevelSelectorPicker

// Weekly Activity Level Selector Text Field End 2 //

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// First Meal Time Text Field Start 2 //

    FirstMealTimeTextField.delegate = self

// First Meal Time Text Field End 2 //

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Selectors Start 1 //

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == GenderSelectorPicker {
        output = 1
    } else if pickerView == HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        output = 2
    } else if pickerView == HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        output = 3
    } else if pickerView == CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        output = 4
    } else if pickerView == CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        output = 5
    } else if pickerView == CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorPicker {
        output = 6
    } else if pickerView == WeeklyActivityLevelSelectorPicker {
        output = 7
    }

    switch output{
    case 1:
        return GenderSelectorData.count
    case 2:
        return HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorData.count
    case 3:
        return HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorData.count
    case 4:
        return CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorData.count
    case 5:
        return CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorData.count
    case 6:
        return CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorData.count
    case 7:
        return WeeklyActivityLevelTextFieldData.count
    default:
        return 1
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == GenderSelectorPicker {
        output2 = 1
    } else if pickerView == HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        output2 = 2
    } else if pickerView == HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        output2 = 3
    } else if pickerView == CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        output2 = 4
    } else if pickerView == CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        output2 = 5
    } else if pickerView == CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorPicker {
        output2 = 6
    } else if pickerView == WeeklyActivityLevelSelectorPicker {
        output2 = 7
    }

    switch output2{
    case 1:
        return GenderSelectorData[row]
    case 2:
        return HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorData[row]
    case 3:
        return HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorData[row]
    case 4:
        return CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorData[row]
    case 5:
        return CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorData[row]
    case 6:
        return CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorData[row]
    case 7:
        return WeeklyActivityLevelTextFieldData[row]
    default:
        return ""
    }
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView == GenderSelectorPicker {
        GenderSelectorTextField.text = GenderSelectorData[row]
    } else if pickerView == HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorTextField.text = HeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorData[row]
    } else if pickerView == HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorTextField.text = HeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorData[row]
    } else if pickerView == CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorTextField.text = CurrentWeightWholeNumberUnitSelectorData[row]
    } else if pickerView == CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorPicker {
        CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorTextField.text = CurrentWeightDecimalNumberUnitSelectorData[row]
    } else if pickerView == CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorPicker {
        CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorTextField.text = CurrentFitnessGoalSelectorData[row]
    } else if pickerView == WeeklyActivityLevelSelectorPicker {
        WeeklyActivityLevelTextField.text = WeeklyActivityLevelTextFieldData[row]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - creating a textfield in a textfield delegate callback doesn't make any sense. I see IBOutlet declaration so I assume you are using storyboards.
If that is so, then you already have all the textfield instances in your scene. 
Just create an outlet from **EACH** textfield to the controller so that you can reference them in code if necessary.

Next, all the textfield will call the same delegate or target/action methods. So inside EACH of those methods, you need to find out WHICH textfield is calling it and deal with it particularly.

```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textfield: UITextField) {

    if textField == self.textField1 {
       //do something to textfield1 
   }
    else if textfield == textfield2 {
      //do something to textfield2
    } 
etc....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should probably start by letting you know that I am a complete novice when it comes to coding (i.e. I've never done it before in my life and I'm currently learning from stackoverflow and youtube so please forgive my lack of understanding. I am using storyboards to create this app. I assume when you say "create an outlet from each textfield" is what I'm doing with the @IBOutlets? Regarding the "if" and "else if" statements, I'm not sure where I should put them. I have used them before for the other pickers but I'm struggling on figuring out how to arrange the time ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue and went down the same exact path you did. Using the resolution Earl Grey gave, I was able to resolve my conflict. Take a look at my code and you should be able to figure yours out. My best advice to you is to not think about the fields as two separate bits of code like you've done, but rather, one bit of code with the use of IF statements.

```
import UIKit

class AddEventViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var eventStartDateTimeText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var eventEndDateTimeText: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        eventStartDateTimeText.delegate = self
        eventEndDateTimeText.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: TextField Delegate

    func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        formatter.dateStyle = .full
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        eventStartDateTimeText.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }

    func datePickerChangedEnd(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()

        formatter.dateStyle = .full
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        eventEndDateTimeText.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)
    }


    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == self.eventStartDateTimeText {
            let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
            textField.inputView = datePicker

            datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        } else if textField == self.eventEndDateTimeText  {
            let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
            textField.inputView = datePicker

            datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChangedEnd(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == self.eventStartDateTimeText {
            eventStartDateTimeText.resignFirstResponder()
        } else if textField == self.eventEndDateTimeText {
            eventEndDateTimeText.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        return true
    }

    // MARK: Helper Methods

    func closekeyboard() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    // MARK: Touch Events

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        closekeyboard()
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */
}
```